# vb.net bigger than decimal data type

Tags: vb.net, cryptography

I am using VB.net and I want to make some cryptographic computations with keys length 1024bit (128bytes). I do not want to use a know algorithm thus I cannot use the Security library.
The biggest data type in vb.net is decimal (16bytes).

how can I do those computations? is there a different data type that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to check [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) in .NET 4.0.

Also you may find it interesting to check [Large Number Calculations in VB.NET](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2007/12/15/large-number-calculations.htm)

Comment: While you could use `BigInteger` for prototyping, it's not suitable for production quality crypto code. For example it suffers from timing attacks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be instructive, even if you're not going to use them, to inspect the existing classes in the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

You'll note that most of the methods that need to deal with keys, blocks, etc, are specced in terms of `byte[]`. A `byte[]` can be as big as you want/need it to be.

---

(Insert usual warnings about rolling your own crypto code)